# SSL errors using Service Fabric ServicePartitionClient

Tags: c#, ssl, azure-service-fabric

We have a singleton service fabric service that needs to communicate to a partitioned service, both of which are running in a secure cluster with certificate-based authentication. We are using `ServicePartitionClient` to do the talking. What follows is a simplified version of our implementations of `ICommunicationClient` and `ICommunicationClientFactory` as required by the `ServicePartitionClient`.

The client:

```
public class HttpCommunicationClient : ICommunicationClient
{
    // Lots of fields omitted for simplicity.

    public HttpCommunicationClient(HttpClientWrapper client, Uri baseAddress)
    {
        this.HttpClient = client;
        this.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    }

    public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }

    // Wraps System.Net.Http.HttpClient to do stuff like add default headers
    public HttpClientWrapper HttpClient { get; }

    public ResolvedServicePartition ResolvedServicePartition { get; set; }

    public string ListenerName { get; set; }

    public ResolvedServiceEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }

    public Uri GetUri(string relativeUri)
    {
        return new Uri(this.BaseAddress, relativeUri);
    }
}
```

The factory:

```
// Note that this base class is under the
// Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client namespace,
// it's not something we wrote
public class HttpCommunicationClientFactory : 
    CommunicationClientFactoryBase<HttpCommunicationClient>
{
    // Lots of fields omitted for simplicity.

    private readonly HttpClientWrapper client;

    public HttpCommunicationClientFactory(
        ServicePartitionResolver resolver,
        IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers)
        : base(resolver, exceptionHandlers, null)
    {
        // There's a bunch of other args that are omitted for clarity.
        this.client = new HttpClientWrapper();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpCommunicationClient> CreateClientAsync(
        string endpoint,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpCommunicationClient client = new HttpCommunicationClient(
            this.client,
            new Uri(endpoint));

        if (this.ValidateClient(endpoint, client))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(client);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(HttpCommunicationClient client)
    {
        // Not much to validate on httpclient 
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(
        string endpoint,
        HttpCommunicationClient client)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endpoint);
    }

    protected override void AbortClient(HttpCommunicationClient client)
    {
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how everything is being constructed and used:

```
internal class FooFabricClient : IDisposable
{
    // Lots of fields omitted for simplicity.

    private readonly HttpCommunicationClientFactory clientFactory;

    private readonly ServicePartitionClient<HttpCommunicationClient> partitionClient;

    public FooFabricClient(Uri fabricUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey = null)
    {
        this.clientFactory = new HttpCommunicationClientFactory(
            ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault());
        this.partitionClient = new ServicePartitionClient<HttpCommunicationClient>(
            this.clientFactory,
            fabricUri,
            partitionKey,
            retrySettings: new OperationRetrySettings());
    }

    public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
    {
        return await this.partitionClient.InvokeWithRetryAsync(async (client) =>
        {
            // Note: See above for actual GetUri() implementation and context,
            // but this will give us a Uri composed of the client's BaseAddress
            // (passed in during HttpCommunicationClientFactory.CreateClientAsync())
            // followed by "/foo"
            Uri requestUri = client.GetUri("foo");
            return await client.HttpClient.GetAsync<Foo>(requestUri);
        });
    }
```

Now, the issue is that when I call `GetFooAsync()`, it throws an exception saying this:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

After some debugging, we found that this is most likely due to the fact that we get the internal service fabric IP address (e.g., `10.0.0.4`) as `HttpCommunicationClient.BaseAddress`, so when we make our API call the server cert doesn't validate against the domain in the request. As a temporary fix we've done the following in the calling service:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => true;
```

Of course, we'd rather not just blindly say "yup, looks good" when validating server certs, so how should we go about resolving this issue? Is there another way to set up the client(s) so that they can properly validate the server cert on the request without needing our own callback? Or do we just need to put acceptable thumbprints in our config and compare against those in the `ServicePointManager` callback or whatever?

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using SF Remoting for internal communication? And is the use of HTTPS strictly necessary inside the cluster?

Comment: Not using remoting because I didn't know about it and other parts of our code (some dependent services) are using the same pattern as described above. At this point converting to use remoting would be fairly time-consuming, but it seems possibly worthwhile as it would also reduce some complexity as far as controllers and clients and all that go. And I'm not sure whether HTTPS is absolutely necessary inside the cluster, but I wouldn't be surprised to learn there's some security requirement on encrypted communication.

Comment: I assume that if you put the certificate(s) into the Trusted People certificate store of the account that is used to run Service Fabric on each of the machines that host Service Fabric, then you won't need to specify thumbprints in your code. Our code actually specifies the thumbprints, which is the other alternative that you mentioned.

Comment: Did you solve this?